# PC won't boot with screen connected via HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, adapter, display-adapter

My old PC won't boot if I have exclusively one screen connected via HDMI. 
It does boot however if I have a second screen connected via VGA.
It also boots when I don't have any screens connected at all.

So I can use this screen via HDMI only when I either:
a) also have a second screen on VGA connected all the time, can be even disconnected from AC
b) or disconnect the HDMI before starting PC and connect it after PC boots

But obviously neither of these options are convenient. How can I make my PC boot with this  troublesome screen?

Specs
- PC: Optiplex 790
- Graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 5450,
- screen on HDMI: CHG90.
- **Graphics drivers and BIOS are up-to-date.**
- **no VGA and HDMI connectors**,
- the graphics card has only a single DVI interface (splitted into dual DVI) and I'm using DVI/VGA and DVI/HDMI adapters to plug my screens into it

Comment: If the computer is old enough, the BIOS probably does not recognize HDMI but just VGA.  So there may not be a way around this issue.

Comment: You don’t mention any specs. Where’s the HDMI connector you use? On the mainboard? On a dedicated CPU? What about the VGA connector?

Comment: @DanielB there are no VGA and HDMI connectors, my graphics card has only a single DVI interface (splitted into dual DVI) and I'm using adapters to plug into it

Comment: (Meant graphics card of course above.) Either way, please add this information plus any relevant specs to your question. If possible, including graphics card make and model.

Comment: @DanielB updated